# How to run Java command in Powershell

Tags: java, powershell

I am trying to run a command in powershell script.

I am able to run this below code in cmd and I am getting the desired result because the jar file is built this way and I cannot change it.

Invoke the jar in CMD as below:

```
java -jar session_reciever.jar "20190423-SESSION" "SESSION_RECIEVED_ACTUAL_TIME$2019-04-23 16:52:05"
```

1st argument is the session name & second is the column name (in database) & time value separated  with $

Result of this is It will update the time value passed for column "SESSION_RECIEVED_ACTUAL_TIME" and session value "20190423-SESSION"

But in Windows Powershell I don't achieve this result.

```
$script_path    = $myinvocation.invocationname;      
$script_folder  = split-path $script_path -parent;
$factory_home = split-path $script_folder -parent;
$COPS_factory_home = split-path $factory_home -parent;
$COPS_factory_root = split-path $COPS_factory_home -parent;

$session_processor_dir=$COPS_factory_home+'\FACTORY_DISTRIBUTOR\bin\session_processor'
echo $session_processor_dir
$session='20190423-SESSION' ### remove this later

$java_bin=$COPS_FACTORY_HOME+'\FACTORY_DISTRIBUTOR\bin\jdk1.7.0_67\jre\bin'

        $nas_time = '2019-04-23 18:34:06' ##(Get-content $nas_time_file)

$session_nas_qe =$java_bin+'\java.exe -jar '+$session_processor_dir+'\session_reciever.jar "+$session+" "+SESSION_RECIEVED_ACTUAL_TIME+$+$nas_time+"'
                echo $session_nas_qe 
                Invoke-expression $session_nas_qe
```

Output of this is:

```
\\COPS_FACTORY\FACTORY_DISTRIBUTOR\bin\session_processor
\\COPS_FACTORY\FACTORY_DISTRIBUTOR\bin\jdk1.7.0_67\jre\bin\java.exe -jar \\Vcn.ds.volvo.net\appl-fs\ERP-CDEVM\PDMLINK-CDE-MA\COPS_FACTORY\FACTORY_DISTRIBUT
OR\bin\session_processor\session_reciever.jar  20190423-SESSION "SESSION_RECIEVED_ACTUAL_TIME$2019-04-23 18:34:06"
```

Error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (java.lang.Array...ndsException: 1:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
    at Session_reciever_less_connection.main(Session_reciever_less_connection.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:50)
```

Please let me know how this can work out using powershell.

Comment: Going by you rinitial example you're missing quotes around your first argument. Is there a particular reason why you're using `Invoke-Expression` rather than say `Start-Process` or similar?

Comment: I am unsure if we use the single quotes or double quotes to get the result? Which type of quotes should I use? For invoking I am using `Invoke-Expression` the whole expression as its there in the other lines of my code. Will `Start-Process` would do good?

Comment: Your Output lists 20190423-SESSION as the argument while you rinitial example has "20190423-SESSION". Did you try to add quotes to that argument? If I'm reading your script correctly `$session='"20190423-SESSION"'` should add them. As for `Invoke-Expression` vs. `Start-Process` it kind of depends on your needs. Assuming that java is properly added to the path just running `$session_nas_qe = java -jar ($session_processor_dir+'\session_reciever.jar') "$session" "$("SESSION_RECIEVED_ACTUAL_TIME$" + $nas_time)"` should work. Have a look at the `Invoke-Expression` and its remarks.